# If I get a 500 internal server error in Scrapy, how do I skip the URL?

Tags: python, scrapy, http-status-codes

I'm scraping data off several thousand pages with the general URL of:

```
http://example.com/database/?id=(some number)
```

where I am running through the id numbers.

I keep encountering huge chunks of URLs that generate a 500 internal server error, and scrapy goes over these chunks several times for some reason. This eats up a lot of time, so I am wondering if there is a way to just move onto the next URL immediately and not have scrapy send requests several times.

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html - Have you looked at this. It seems retry is enabled by default.  I skimmed it though and did not read it deeply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The component retrying 500 errors is [RetryMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=retrymiddleware#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry).

If you do not want Scrapy to retry requests that received 500 status code, in your `settings.py` you can set `RETRY_HTTP_CODES` to not include 500 (default is `[500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 408]`), or disable the RetryMiddleware altogether with `RETRY_ENABLED = False`

See [RetryMiddleware settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=retrymiddleware#retrymiddleware-settings) for more.